# VS Code can't find header-files - Linux VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, header-files

I haven't compiled through VS Code but trying to set it up. Im running in to a issue where the compiler can't find the path to the header files.

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/path/to/project/file.c).
```

I tried adding this line to c_cpp_properties.json

```
"includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${HOME}/path/to/code_base/structure/include/"
        ],
```

Here is my tree if it helps:

```
└── course
├── code_base
│   └── datastructures
│       ├── ChangeLog.txt
│       ├── CODING_STYLE.md
│       ├── include
│       │   └── array_1.h
│       ├── lib
│       │   └── Makefile
│       ├── README.md
│       └── src
└── projects
    └── int_array_1_mwe
        ├── int_array_1.c
        └── int_array_1_mwe.c
```

Update:
Since restarting computer the code actually compiles and works, so the problem seems to be with only VSCode/IntelliSense.

Solution:
Seems like the issue is with include path needing to be explicit:

Ctrl + Shift + P -> **C/C++ Edit configurations (UI)**

On **Include path** you need to add a line with the explicit locating of your folder with header files, for example:

> /home/joe/edu/course/code_base/datastructures/include

I don't if this is a Linux-only issue but it worked for me.

Comment: The error seems to be VSCode and IntelliSense only, not related to the compiler. Where are the missing header files located? Have you tried using `"${HOME}/path/to/code_base/structure/include/**"` (assuming that's the root directory for *all* the missing header files)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, tried that aswell. Also tried:
"~/path/to/code_base/code_base/include/" and ""~/path/to/code_base/code_base/include"

Comment: Can you provide some details of one affected file name? Do you have a file name with a relative path in it? What is the real locatin in file system? What is the name in your `#include' directive and what is the path you provide in VSCode?

Comment: Lets see if I understand your questions right. The project I'm working on is located in 'HOME/edu/course/projects/int_array/', where I'm trying to compile the file int_array.c with include '#include <int_array_1.h>'. The header file is located in: 'HOME/edu/course/code_base/datastructures/include'

Comment: With your `int_array` example (and assuming that `$HOME/edu/course/projects/int_array` is your `workspaceFolder`) then using only `"${workspaceFolder}/**"` should have worked for VSCode and its IntelliSense. To make the compiler use the directory you need to modify your `tasks.json` file to add the proper directory with the compiler `-I` option, like `"-I${workspaceFolder}/include"` (as a compiler argument).

Comment: Thanks. I had already put this in tasks.json:
  "-I",
  "~/edu/course/code_base/datastructures/include/",

But I tried yours aswell, with same result.

Comment: Can't figure out how to make a code block in the comments, I have updated the original post with tree if that helps

Comment: You should not include your own header file name in `<>` but use `" "` instead.

Comment: @Gerhardh That would be the case if I don't have a include folder and hadn't added the include path to the c_cpp_properties.json. But that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to an environment variable in a VS Code configuration file, you need to use the proper syntax. See [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables). Your `${HOME}` should instead be `${env:HOME}`.